# Configuring a Wired Access Point - Linksys WRT54G

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

For the last few weeks I have been trying to configure a wired access point. Eventually I want this to be wireless, but I thought best start with wired. Below are some details

**Hardware**

- Broadband connection – Cable modem
- Router A - Linksys WRT54G V8 -> Configured as wireless
- Router B - Linksys WRT54G V2.2 -> Attempting to configure as wired

**Current Status**

Router is configured for DHCP. The wireless network is and has been working for longtime. I am trying to add another wired access point.

**Current Network Configuration**

- Router A IP: 192.168.x1.y1
- Router A DHCP server: enabled
- Starting IP address 192.168.x1.y150
- Maximum number of DHPC user 50

**Basic Wireless settings**

- Wireless Network Mode: Mixed
- Wireless Network Name (SSID): Router_A
- Wireless Channel: 6
- Wireless SSID broadcast enabled
- Wireless Security Mode: WEP (Testing)

**New Network extension**

Wiring Considerations: Wired Ethernet CAT cable from Router A LAN port to Router B LAN port

- Router A settings are the same
- Router B Internet Connection Type : Automatic Configuration - DHCP
- Router B IP: 192.168.x1.254
- Router B DHCP server **disable**
- Starting IP address 192.168.x1.100
- Maximum number of DHPC user 50

The above was primary followed from “[How to Convert to Be an Access Point](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Linksys-WRT54G-to-Be-an-Access-Point)”

I also have tried [Converting Cheap Router to Wireless AP Instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oenmXhN9sqA)

I posted the same question on ["Configuring a Wired Access Point](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8060/configuring-a-wired-access-point)", and was suggested that I try superuser forum.

I also have read the following post ["Incorrect configuration of Linksys WRT54GL as wired router with Linsys WRT54GS as wireless access point"](https://superuser.com/questions/349757/incorrect-configuration-of-linksys-wrt54gl-as-wired-router-with-linsys-wrt54gs-a)

I hope someone can shed some light on what is wrong in my setup.

Comment: Are you trying to create a *wireless bridge* such that Router B takes data from wired clients and forwards it over WiFi to Router A? Or do you have a cable between Router A and Router B, and you simply need a *network switch* at Router B's location to share it with other wired clients?

Comment: 1. There's no such thing as a `wired access point` unless you consider a switch a `wired access point`. 2. Stop using Router B as a router and start using it as a switch. 3. Alternately you could use Router B as a wireless bridge, but in any event you need to stop using it as a router.

Comment: You should have DHCP disbaled on Router B, other than that the setup looks good.   What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: @DarthAndroid, its pretty clear from the "New Network Extension" section that there is a cable from Router A to Router B.

Comment: @joeqwerty, he's not using Router B as a router, he has a cable running from a LAN port in A to a LAN port in B, so no WAN is being used, so its not doing any routing.

Comment: My bad. I didn't see that. Apologies.

Comment: I apologize for incorrect terminology. In short I want to extend router A to route B. Ideally I would like Router B to be wireless. If I can get Router B working wire, then I will try to get wireless working.

Comment: Symptoms: With the above configuration, I cannot get internet working for windows machines on router A. Internet works on the Ubuntu machine. Also internet working on Router_B (Switch) on both ubuntu and windows machines.

Comment: Please update the question to use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cascading Router to another Router**

The following configuration is considered to be LAN-WAN configuration.

**Steps**

1. Note the current configuration on a Main Router - Router_A (On Windows machines access the command prompt and execute a ipconfig/All Command)
2. Reset the Router B if it has been previous configured to factor setting, connect a computer using a CAT able to an Ethernet port of Router B
3. Using a web browser access the setup page of Router B. For Linksys WRT54G enter 192.168.1.1 at the URL.
4. Enter a different IP address for Router B. Example: If Router A is 192.168.1.1 then select 192.168.2.1 for Router B.
5. Make sure the DHPC server is enabled for the Router B.
6. Save the setting.
7. Unplug the CAT cable from the Computer and Router B.
8. Connect the one end of CAT to Router A LAN Ethernet port and other end to Router B **WAN** port.
9. Power Cycle the Router B.
10. Connect the CAT cable between the Router B Ethernet port and the second computer.

**Note:** Router B can be configured to be a wireless router.

More detail information can be found [here](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?vw=1&docid=785463d9ecaf4cac84aed245b08d615f_3733.xml&pid=80&respid=0&snid=1&dispid=0&cpage=search) for LINKSYS WRT54G routers.